# TableView animation when the cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I would like to animate the tableView cell when the user put is finger on it like in this image [image]

and when the user stop pressing, the cell come back in the original size (my tableView is not using a custom cell but the default UItableViewCell). I looked around the net to find some tutorial or something useful but nothing, someone can tell me how can i do?

Comment: You can add tap gesture recognizer to your table view cell’s custom view and handle the scale using the affine transformation on the view’s layer

Comment: @deathhorse so i have to add the tap gesture recognizer on the cell in storyboard? how i can handle the scale using the affine transformation on the view’s layer? (sorry i'm beginner)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

On Touch Down Event for UITableViewCell:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: [],animations: {
            self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.95, 0.95)
            }, completion: { finished in

        })
```

And On Touch Up Event for UITableViewCell:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .CurveEaseIn,animations: {
            self.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
            },completion: { finished in

        })
```

Hope this will help you.